# The C Program dynamically loads file

Tags: c, unix

My Program is running on Solaris, and the structure likes this:

```
{
    parse configuration file and construct hash tables in memory
    spawn multi threads to access hash tables
    ......
}
```

Because program depends on configuration file to construct hash tables, after modifying configuration file, I need to restart the program.

Now I want to load configuration file dynamically, that is after modifying configuration file, send a signal to the program, and the program reloads the file and updates hash tables in memory.

The only method I can come out is using exec family functions to reload the program after receiving the signal. can anyone suggest good ideas? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have your program check for the configuration file's mtime once in a while?

Comment: No, don't check. Thanks!

Comment: I think 1st comment was a suggestion: let you program periodically check the last modified time of the config file in a sperate thread and update the hashtables if necessary. Or are you anot allowed to do such a check in your program?

Comment: Because there are many threads access the hash tables simulataneously, when a seperate thread updates hash tables, I think there are contention issues. So personally, I think this method isn't easy to follow up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FAM](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fam/) to sense when the configuration file changes.

When the file(s) change, you lock the tables, repopulate them, and signal all threads that the config changed, if their internal states depend on this.

Comment: I think locking tables can't resolve contention issue, because although locking tables can avoid other threads access it, but before locking it, other threads may have the value of tables. So if repopulate it now, other threads may use invalid value now, this may cause program down.

Comment: What about adding a signal, that says "wait, the table got invalidated", broadcasting to all threads?